# Access modal view controller parent

Tags: iphone, ios

I'm presenting a ViewController modally.
How can I access the parent view controller ?

My architecture is TabBarController=>VC1=>VC2=>VC3=>MVC1, and I want to reach VC3 from MVC1.

In VC3, I have this code :

```
- (void) editAd{
    AskPasswordViewController *modalViewController = [[AskPasswordViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"AskPasswordView" bundle:nil];

    NSLog(@"modalparent class=%@", [[modalViewController parentViewController] class]);

    [self presentModalViewController:modalViewController animated:YES];
    [modalViewController release];
}
```

I tried this in MVC1:

```
- (void) sendRequest {
    NSLog(@"classe : %@",[[self parentViewController] class] );
}
```

but it returns my TabBarViewController...

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The way I'd go about something like this is to simply create a delegate.  In `AskPasswordViewController`'s header, put

```
id delegate;
```

and

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) id delegate;
```

Synthesize it in the implementation file.  Then after you alloc/init the modal controller, and before you present it, set `modalViewController.delegate = self;`.  Then within the modal controller, you can call `self.delegate` to get information from the view controller that presented it.  I hope this helps

Comment: Thanks. That is what i have done in the end. But I'd like to understand why the parent view controller is the tabbar. It seems really weird, and I'm afraid to have done something wrong somewhere.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure why, but my theory is that since you are presenting a modal view, it is not necessarily a child of the view controller that presents it, but instead part of it.  Therefore its parent is the parent of the view that presents it as it's an extension.  It seems to have a different behavior in this aspect as opposed to pushing a view through a navigation controller

Comment: it worked for me as well. But I had to make the delegate of the class "parentviewcontroller". I wanted to access the uitabbar of the "parentviewcontroller".

Comment: It's worth pointing out that this is Apple's officially recommended solution to this problem, as detailed in the Presenting a "View Controller and Choosing a Transition Style" section here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ModalViewControllers/ModalViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH111-SW3

Answer (score 98):

You can access parent by calling:

```
self.presentingViewController
```

As per apple documentation:

> The view controller that presented this view controller (or its
>   farthest ancestor.)

Comment: Whilst the other comments were right at their time, I think this is the way to go with storyboards (especially since iOS 7)

Comment: Just an FYI this will be nil in viewDidLoad

Answer (score 7):

You can always go further back just by calling parentViewController like so:

`self.parentViewController.parentViewController` .... and so on until you reach the right one.

Comment: I have a tabbar, which present the navigationController, which push some viewcontroller, which present the annoying viewController.

Comment: well in your question give us a feed back like so telling us you modalviewcontroller archtecture  vc1 -> vc2 -> nvc -> tbvc and then tell us from where to where you want to get.

Comment: To print the acctual class name use this: `NSLog(@"clase : %@",NSStringFromClass[[self parentViewController] class]) );`

Comment: You should be just fine calling self.parentViewController from MVC1. It will reach VC3.

Answer (score 7):

Addition to Vibhor Goyal
- Sometimes, self.presentingViewController registers as NavigationController. Therefore try:

```
if let vc = self.presentingViewController.childViewControllers.last as? YourViewController {
// do stuff here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here I came up with universal method to navigate from any place to root.

1. You create a new Class file with this class, so that it's accessible from anywhere in your project:

   ```
   import UIKit

   class SharedControllers
   {
       static func navigateToRoot(viewController: UIViewController)
       {
           var nc = viewController.navigationController

           // If this is a normal view with NavigationController, then we just pop to root.
           if nc != nil
           {
               nc?.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)
               return
           }

           // Most likely we are in Modal view, so we will need to search for a view with NavigationController.
           let vc = viewController.presentingViewController

           if nc == nil
           {
               nc = viewController.presentingViewController?.navigationController
           }

           if nc == nil
           {
               nc = viewController.parentViewController?.navigationController
           }

           if vc is UINavigationController && nc == nil
           {
               nc = vc as? UINavigationController
           }

           if nc != nil
           {
               viewController.dismissViewControllerAnimated(false, completion:
                   {
                       nc?.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)
               })
           }
       }
   }
   ```
2. Usage from anywhere in your project:

   ```
   {
       ...
       SharedControllers.navigateToRoot(self)
       ...
   }
   ```

Comment: That's bad practice!

Answer (score 0):

```
//You have to get the root, iterate through the root's ViewControllers and then ask for the ParentViewController.
    UINavigationController ​*root = (UINavigationController*​)[[(AppDelegate*) [[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate] window] rootViewController];
           for (UIViewController *VC in root.viewControllers) {
               if([VC isKindOfClass:[YourParentViewController class]]){
                   YourParentViewController*  parent = (YourParentViewController*)VC;
                   [parent callMethod]; // your code here
                   [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
               }
           }
```

Answer (score 0):

If `presentingViewController` gives you unexpected results and you don't want to fiddle with it, just do:

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController {

    private weak var presenter: UIViewController?

    init(presenter: UIViewController) {
        self.presenter = presenter
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
        ...
    }
    
    ...
}
```