# How to know which view controller presented a view controller

Tags: ios, swift

I have several view controllers ('From' view controllers) connected to one view controller `ItemCollectionVC`.
When `ItemCollectionVC` is presented, I want to know which view controller presented it.
How to do that?

**'From' view controllers:**

```
@IBAction func selectOpponentItems(_ sender: UIButton) {

    let VC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ItemCollectionVC") as! ItemCollectionVC
    VC.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 2, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height / 1.5)
    VC.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.popover
    VC.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = sender
    VC.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = sender.bounds

    self.present(VC, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

**ItemViewController:**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.collectionView!.register(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
}
```

Edit:

I'm trying to access the property this way:

```
 switch self.presentingViewController!.title! {
 // Error
    case "CounterBuildVC":
        dataSourceItems = counterBuildItems
    case "FreeBuildVC":
        dataSourceItems = freeBuildItems
    case "KrakenViewController":
        dataSourceItems = captureKrakenItems
    default:
        break
    }
```

> However, it crashes with error: unexpectedly found nil, I'm sure I set
>   the title in storyboard

Comment: You can achieve this by `self.presentingViewController` method.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access modal view controller parent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6735170/access-modal-view-controller-parent)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`presentingViewController`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621430-presentingviewcontroller) property of `UIViewController` is the thing you're looking for

Comment: That property seemed to be nil when I ran it

Comment: It seems that until the vc is not presented this property is not, so you can use this property in viewWillAppear/viewDidAppear

Answer (score 1):

The way I'd go about something like this is to simply create a delegate in ItemCollectionVC header:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) id delegate;
```

set:

```
VC.delegate = self;
```

Then within the ItemCollectionVC controller, you can call self.delegate to get information from the view controller that presented it. I hope this helps

Cheers!

Please note:

```
self.presentingViewController; //This would be nil in viewDidLoad, so yeah not completely useful here
```

Comment: This seem to be a really cool method but honestly, I don't really understand

Answer (score 0):

You can get the view controller by using  `self.presentingViewController`

Answer (score 0):

If you presented ViewControllerB from ViewControllerA. then in ViewControllerB you can check the presented ViewController by the follwing code

```
if([self.presentingViewController isKindOfClass:[ViewControllerA class]]){ 
               /*Write your Code here*/
}
```